# Relationships With My_Model

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am attempting to find out how to understand the use of *Jamie Rumbelow's MY_Model* in specific of how to implement this idea.

I'm putting a game app together. There are many users and many characters. Each user can have many characters but only each character can be controlled by one user. I have a user's table that has a field called `default_character`. This is the foreign key that is represented by the id field of the character.

In my code I am using the following function call to get the current logged in user.

```
$user_data = $this->user->get_by('username', $post_username);
```

What I would like to do is when I do this and it adds in the integer value from the default_character field instead I would like for it to go get the name of that character. What would this look like?

EDIT :

For some reason after attempting *swatkins* answer below its still only showing the number string value from the database. What I"m wanting to do is use it to get the character_name from the characters table.

tables

```
user - user_id, username, default_character_id

characters - id, character_name

object(stdClass)#23 (12) {
    ["user_id"]=>
    string(5) "10003"
    ["first_name"]=>
    string(3) "tom"
    ["last_name"]=>
    string(8) "williams"
    ["username"]=>
    string(9) "twilliams"
    ["password"]=>
    string(40) "431db25cf8fe0ccf374365ae9c644c7bfdeb7399"
    ["password_hash"]=>
    string(11) "ed95d918116"
    ["email_address"]=>
    string(19) "twilliams@yahoo.com"
    ["status_id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["lock_date"]=>
    string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    ["default_character_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["created_at"]=>
    string(19) "2013-07-30 10:00:00"
    ["updated_at"]=>
    string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
}
```

User Model(application/modules/user/models/user_model.php) (Loaded in MY_Controller)

```
<?php

class User_model extends MY_Model 
{    
    public $primary_key = 'user_id';
    public $has_many = array('characters' => array('model' => 'character_model' ));

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Character Model(application/modules/character/models/character_model.php)(Loaded in control panel controller)

```
<?php

class Character_model extends MY_Model 
{    
    public $belongs_to = array('user' => array('primary_key' => 'default_character_id'));

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if this is a database structure issue. Any more thoughts on this topic? Any help would be great.

I'm still having some concerns on what I'm doing wrong. Anybody able to help me out?

Comment: Sorry about this useless comment, but this is one of the best question titles I've ever seen in Stackoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you've set up your relationships correctly, you access children of the relationship with the `with` method:

https://github.com/jamierumbelow/codeigniter-base-model

```
// from the docs

$post = $this->post_model->with('author')
                     ->with('comments')
                     ->get(1);

echo $post->author->name;

foreach ($post->comments as $comment)
{
    echo $message;
}
```

So, this blog grabs the `post` with an id of `1`, then also grabs the `author` and array of `comments`. You access them as properties of the parent object.

**UPDATE**

You need to set up your relationships in your models. So, you would set up your `user` and `character` entities like this:

```
class User_model extends MY_Model
{
  public $has_many = array('characters');
}

class Character_model extends MY_Model
{
  public $belongs_to = array('user' => array('primary_key' => 'default_character'));
}
```

Comment: I'm still struggling with this because I don't understand how it knows to join the two with users.default_character with characters.id.

Comment: You tell it how to join the two. I've updated my answer explaining how to set up those relationships.

Comment: I'm still struggling with this for some reason. I've made an edit above.

Comment: Ok, so when you do this:  `$user = $this->user_model->with('character')->get(1);`  ---  what does `print_r($user);` show?

Comment: It still shows the integer value and doesn't get the name of the character which is what it should be adding on

Comment: Well, that's the correct way to do it. Do you know which version of MY_Model you're using?

Comment: I have no idea which version it is. It was a file I downloaded months ago. I have my table's listed above.

Comment: Are you afraid to look at the code? Jamie's great at commenting his stuff. The version number should be towards the top of the file.

Comment: That's odd because I must not have the latest version because its not on there. Ill have to paste in what my model I have to show.

Comment: OK, first off, I'd grab the latest version and try that. If that doesn't work, then I'd start debugging the model itself - starting at line 451 -- https://github.com/jamierumbelow/codeigniter-base-model/blob/master/core/MY_Model.php#L451

Comment: That's odd because its the same exact model. Look at the table tructure again. Are you sure I'm doing it right?

Comment: Do you have any more ideas?

Comment: No, not without setting up your entire environment and I just don't have time to do that. Why don't you add `$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);` to your method. This will give you the raw SQL that will be executed. Maybe that will give you an idea of what is wrong.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me. For some reason it's not attaching on the join.

Comment: Can you provide the SQL statement?

Comment: SELECT *
FROM (`users`)
WHERE `user_id` =  '10003'

Comment: With how I have my tables set up in my post I think the has many and belongs to is wrong in my individual models but i don't know.

Comment: Well, it sounds like you're trying to use the `has_many` relationship incorrectly. If I understand correctly, a user can have many characters, but it has one default_character. So, it sounds like you should make a separate relationship for the default_character which would be that the `user` belongs to `character`. I know that seems backwards, but I think that is how the relationship works within the model.

Comment: What I was hoping it would do is when it comes to the default_character_id of the user object it would make that an object under the user as it is now and then do the additional query to take that value and get the character name and amke it appear like object(stdClass)#23 (12) {
    ["user_id"]=>
    string(5) "10003"
    ["default_character"] =>
    object(stdClass)#23 (12) {
    ["default_character_id"] => "1" ["character_name"] => "whatever name is ["last_name"]=>
    string(8) "williams"
    ["username"]=>
    string(9) "twilliams"

Comment: Well, you could do it manually (very easy). Jamie's model mentions that it executes 2 statements per relationship, so you could do this and get the desired output:

$user_data = $this->user->get_by('username', $post_username);

$character_data = $this->character->get_by('id', $user_data->default_character_id);  ----------  

$user_data->character = $character_data;  -----------

Comment: Wow that sounds great.

Comment: I don't know the advantage of using get vs. get_by